# How to Get Current Product ID in Magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2

**Method to Get Current Product ID in Magento 2**

There two way for this task

**1. Using Object Manager**

```
    <?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    echo $product->getId();
?>
```

**2. Using block**

```
    <?php 
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block; 
    class BlockClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        protected $registry;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            array $data = []
        )
        {
            $this->registry = $registry;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }
    
        public function _prepareLayout()
        {
            return parent::_prepareLayout();
        }
    
        public function getCurrentProduct()
        {
            return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
        }
    } 
?>
```

**This code add in phtml file where you want to display**

```
 <?php 
$currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();echo $currentProduct->getId();
?>
```

Comment: where you have trying to access?

Comment: Product details page

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

- Number 1, do not use Object manager, this is deprecated from very long time. We use only dependency injection now
- Number 2 : To get the current product (aka current category) the registry seems to be fine, although there is better version at lower level they will end up using registry too i think. So this code should work, if it's not, it's probable a cache issue. That's why I would suggest you to add in the xml definition of the block and template `cacheable=false`